# Cross referencing street and city names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a list of cities and streets in each of the cities. I'm trying to cross reference city names with street names. Below is a simplified example of the lists.

```
City name       Street name

London          Street A
London          Street B
London          Berlin Street

Paris           Street C
Paris           Street D
Paris           London Street

Berlin          Street E
Berlin          Street F
Berlin          Paris Street
```

The output should be something like:

```
Street A   in   City A, City B, City C...
```

What would be the least time consuming way (least time spent on iterating) to do this because I have ~150 cities and ~15 000 streets to cover?

Also as I'm not from an english speaking country some streets with city names have suffixes that change the last few letters of the city name. Something like this: inflat**e** -> inflat**able**
What would be a good workaround to cover these names.

I'm open to any ideas on both questions :)

Edit: My data looks like this. So I've got each city listed with its own streets.

```
            NASELJE_NAZIV(city)             ULICA_NAZIV(Street)
GROP_VRSTA                                       
1           BELI MANASTIR         A. AUGUSTINČIĆA
1           BELI MANASTIR              A. CESARCA
1           BELI MANASTIR       ADOLFA WALDINGERA
1           BELI MANASTIR       ALOJZIJA STEPINCA
1           BELI MANASTIR         ANTE STARČEVIĆA
1           BELI MANASTIR           BANA JELAČIĆA
1           BELI MANASTIR               BARANJSKA
1           BELI MANASTIR            BARTOKA BELE
1           BELI MANASTIR   BELI MANASTIR PLANINA
1           BELI MANASTIR       BELIŠĆANSKA ULICA
1           BELI MANASTIR            BRAČKA ULICA
1           BELI MANASTIR          BRANKA GAVELLE
1           BELI MANASTIR   DONJOMIHOLJAČKA ULICA
1           BELI MANASTIR          DORE PEJAČEVIĆ
1           BELI MANASTIR                 DRAVSKA
1           BELI MANASTIR    DR. KAMILA FIRINGERA
1           BELI MANASTIR                DUNAVSKA
1           BELI MANASTIR         ĐAKOVAČKA ULICA
1           BELI MANASTIR        EUGENA SAVOJSKOG
1           BELI MANASTIR  FRANA KRSTE FRANKOPANA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the changing suffixes you can use FuzzyWuzzy library
https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Comment: Thanks :) I'll give it a try. Do you know if it will work with letter given in the example above?